# rebase over a window of commits

Tags: git

I have a branch with a very messy history

It has commits 1 - X, then a merge commit of (M length).

I'd like to rebase AROUND the merge commit so I don't have to replay all the merge conflicts that come out of the merge conflict.

Any way to do this?

Or should I give up and cherry-pick all the good commits onto another branch?

Comment: Why are you worried about the messy history? Is it causing you problems?

Comment: I just want to improve my git-fu

Answer (score 1):

So you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- M -- E -- F -- G <--(master)
                   /
    ... X -- X -- X
```

and you want to remove the `X` commits (and `M`), correct?

There are a couple ways to do it.  It is a history rewrite, which means two tihngs:

1) If the branch is shared (in a remote repository, or I suppose by passing of bundle files) then you need to be aware of the issues with "upstream rebases"; see the `git rebase` docs, but in summary you'd likely need to coordinate with the other users of the repo.

2) If you have other refs that refer to the commits you replace, they will also need to be updated

So that said, one way to do it is

```
git rebase -i master~4 master
```

(where `master~4` works in this example, but in general what you need is an expression that resolves to commit `D`).  This will start a text editor and show you a "todo list" like)

```
pick 12345678 one of the X commits
pick 23456789 another X commit
pick 01234567 yet another X commit
pick 34567890 commit E
pick 45678901 commit F
pick 54321098 commit G
```

Notice that `M` is already omitted - because by default `rebase` wants to eliminate merges. On the lines for the `X` xommits, change the first word from `pick` to `drop` (or just delete the line).  Then exit the editor.

If any of the commits `E`, `F`, or `G` affect the same hunk of code that any of the `X`s touched, you'll have to resolve it like a merge conflict.  But once things are sorted out, you should get

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E' -- F' -- G' <--(master)
```

Another variation that avoids the interactive work (but maybe is a little trickier to think about) is

```
git rebase --onto master~4 master~3 master
```

This will select the commits reachable from `master` but not reachable from master's 3rd ancestor (`M`) to rewrite - and those are `E`, `F`, and `G` - and it will apply them with `D` as the new parent, "stepping over" `M`.

I should note that these approaches (and any other approach you might cobble together) do not actually delete the `X` or `M` commits, and the rewritten commits are totally new commits that happen to be related to old commits (so, e.g. `E'` is a "replay" of `E`, but it is still a new and distinct commit).  Right after doing this (and, by default, for a while after), you could still get back to the old history using the reflog.